# Spring ternary operators in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'd like to set conditional value on application.properties, for example this works:

`info.dev.env=true
 info.environment=${info.dev.env:Production}`

In this case if `info.dev.env != null` then its value is used (regardless whether it's true or false) on `info.environment` else value is `Production`.

That is all fine but what i really want to achieve is something like this:

`info.dev.env=true
    info.isDevEnv=${info.dev.env?true:false}
    spring.thymeleaf.cache=${info.dev.env?false:true}
    spring.jpa.show-sql=${info.dev.env?true:false}
    etc...`

So if i explicitly set anything to  `info.dev.env` then use left value from ternary operator otherwise right value.

This particular example is not tied to setting development environment i'm just curious if it is possible at all to achieve such login in application.properties.

Comment: Use profiles instead of hacking around like this. create an `application-dev.properties` set the active profile to dev and next to the default `application.properties` this will be loaded, allowing you to override properties.

Comment: You can set multiple, just set `spring.profiles.active` with a comma separated list of profiles. So not sure what makes you think you can only set a single profile..

Comment: Set an environment variable. Why do you want to set it in the main method, that basically m means you are hardcoding your profiles, then what is the use of profiles..

Comment: Ok i missed that `SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles()` accepts `String...` i was thinking it accepts `"profile1,profile2"`, it did the trick actually, but my original question still remains: can there be used ternary operators in `application.properties`

Comment: No you cannot and it is a lot easier to use different profiles to override your defaults... You don't want to program in your property (or xml) files.